# function + swticher in python

Tags: python, function, switchers

I have an issue with the use of functions and switcher in python:
I have this production cost function:

```
def fcostoproduccion (X,periodo):
if X > 0:
    switcher = {
            1:  200 + 15 * X,
            2:  100 + 20 * X,
            3:  100 + 4 * (X ** (1 / 2)),
            4:  100 + 3 * X,
            5:  150 + 6 * X,
            6:  200 + 12 * (X ** (1 / 2)),
            7:  200 + 15 * X,
            8:  100 + 10 * X,
            9:  100 + 6 * (X ** (1 / 2)),
            10: 200 + 5 * (X ** (1 / 2)),
            11: 100 + 10 * X,
            12: 150 + 6 * X

            }
return
```

And at the end I'm trying to look for the value:

```
  for l in range(j+1, k+1):
    Ordenar = O[l] 
    Produccion = fcostoproduccion(Demanda, l)
```

I know I'm making a mistake but don't know how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your goal. Please clarify the expected output.

Comment: The idea is that the variable Production (in the second part) get the value of 1, 2, 3 or 4 according to "L" if demand or X > 0

Comment: I used to have the Cost in a list, something like:                                       C    = [0,20,20,15,15,15,15], and i declared the variable Production as Production = Demand + C[L], but now the production cost depends on the value calculated, something like Production cost = 200 + 15 X1.

Comment: what is `Demanda` ?

Comment: Demand in a specific period.

Comment: just trying to ask: If "demand" > than 0 select the number according to "period" or L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things with the function `fcostoproduccion`:

1. It always returns `None`
2. It has no side effect
3. It makes use of only the first argument passed into it (i.e. the paramenter `periodo` is unsused in the function).

It is hard to discern your intention with the function however I guess

1. you want to compute a value based on `X`
2. The formular to compute the desired return value varies for different values of `X` hence the dictionary `switcher`.

Based on the above assumtions, you can modify the function `fcostoproduccion` as follows:

```
def fcostoproduccion(X):
    switcher = {
    1:  200 + 15 * X,
    2:  100 + 20 * X,
    3:  100 + 4 * (X ** (1 / 2)),
    4:  100 + 3 * X,
    5:  150 + 6 * X,
    6:  200 + 12 * (X ** (1 / 2)),
    7:  200 + 15 * X,
    8:  100 + 10 * X,
    9:  100 + 6 * (X ** (1 / 2)),
    10: 200 + 5 * (X ** (1 / 2)),
    11: 100 + 10 * X,
    12: 150 + 6 * X
    }
    return switcher[X] if X in switcher else None #Handle cases where X switcher is not defined for X 

>>> [fcostoproduccion(i) for i in range(14)]
[None, 215, 140, 106.92820323027551, 112, 180, 229.39387691339815, 305, 180, 118.0, 215.81138830084188, 210, 222, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need the behavior of a good old switch-case. Unfortunately, there is no built-in switch case in python. The preferred way is to use a dictionary. Thus, you are really close. Try replacing your return statement:

```
return switcher[X]
```

Note that you want to return it only if `X > 1`. therefore, make sure to indent your `return` statement and handle the `else` case as you want.

Note that your second argument seems totally useless in this case. So you may want to remove `periodo`.